# Rails date_field not working in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer

I have a search built on date fields. I want to use the date_field instead of date_selector if possible.

The date field works fine in chrome. However, in IE 11, the placeholder and controls do not work.  The date select does work in IE.

```
        <%= f.date_field( :req_resolution_from_date) %>
        <%= f.date_select( :req_resolution_to_date) %>
```

In chrome, both date_field and date_select work.

[image]

However, in IE, only the date_select works

Is there any way to get the date_field to show in IE with the date controls?

[image]

Comment: IE doesn't support native date pickers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime you'd need to use the date_select instead for cross-browser compatibility, or you could use a javascript date picker.

Comment: Thanks - that cleared things up. I'll refactor the date_fields to date_select fields. It appears that edge does support date_fields so when we finally go to edge, I'll revisit this.